# PowerShell enumerate an array that contains only one inner array

Tags: arrays, list, powershell

Conside this:
This is one array and contains only one item. And the item of the array is another array(I call it list object). 
I want to get the only list object inside an array.

I use foreach to get the list, but it treates the list object as an array and return the first item of the list object.

```
$OSName1 = @(
    @("win2008r2")
)
$OSName2 = @(
    @("win2008r2"),
    @("win2012")
)


foreach ($osname in $OSName1) {
    write-host $osname[0]
}

foreach ($osname in $OSName2) {
    write-host $osname[0]
}
```

I expect the output of result is:
win2008r2
win2008r2
win2012

But the real result is 
w
win2008r2
win2012
Why powershell auto expands the inside array to it parent?

Comment: I"m guessing it thinks the first one is just a string so `$osname[0]` is the first character (w)

Comment: But I already point it as an item with @() explicitly

Comment: "Why powershell auto expands the inside array to it parent?" because such is the nature of PowerShell and it's overzealous pipeline :)

Comment: How to avoid it? I tried add @() but it seems that powershell didn't take it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how array construction in general and the `@()` operator in particular work in PowerShell. If you take a look at the value of your 2 array variables you'll notice that only the second one has nested arrays:

```
PS C:\> ConvertTo-Json $OSName1
[
    "win2008r2"
]
PS C:\> ConvertTo-Json $OSName2
[
    [
        "win2008r2"
    ],
    [
        "win2012"
    ]
]
```

That is because the array subexpression operator `@()` evaluates the nested expression and then returns the result as an array. But when you're nesting an array subexpression into another array subexpression the result of the inner subexpression is automatically unrolled upon the evalution of the outer subexpression. Because of that your first variable becomes `['win2008r2']` instead of the intended `[['win2008r2']]`.

Your second example works the way you expect because the outer array subexpression contains not just a nested array subexpression, but an *array* of nested subexpressions:

```
@(...), @(...)
      ^
       `- this comma is what actually creates the array of arrays
```

The outer array subexpression unrolls only the outer array, so that the result is still an array of arrays in the end. Basically, you don't need the outer `@()` for the desired result. Remove it and you will get the exact same result:

```
$OSName2 = @("win2008r2"), @("win2012")
```

To get a similar result with just a single nested array you need to use the unary array construction operator:

```
$OSName1 = ,@("win2008r2")
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding to Ansgar's explanation, you just need a nested array to achieve what you need.

```
$OSName1 = @(
    @("win2008r2")
)
$OSName2 = @(
    @("win2008r2"),
    @("win2012")
)


foreach ($osname in $OSName1) 
{
    $OSName
    foreach($OS2 in $OSName2 )
    {
    $OS2
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Your code doesn't create a nested array (and the arrays are declared the same way as in the question). Did you mean nested _loops_? Why would you need nested loops? It's also not clear how your answer relates to Ansgar's, which explains the real problem.